# Strange condition behaviour in foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach, conditional-statements

If this has been ever discussed before, pardon me I'm new.

So I having troubles with very strange behaviour of IF condition in PHP.

Let's say, I have this code:

```
$userPhotosArray = ([0] => Array(<more values>),
[1] => Array(<more values>));

print("<table>");

foreach ($userPhotosArray as $index => $photoInfo) {
   $ind = $index % 3;

   if ($ind == 0)
      print("<tr>");

   print("<td>");
   print_r($photoInfo);
   print("</td>");

   if ($ind == 0)
      print("</tr>");
}

print("</table>");
```

So this code above SHOULD output only 1 row, but what it does is outputs 2 rows.

Even if I *var_dump* the value of the $ind it's o.k. (with first iteration it's (int)1, second (int)0). Even when I cast it to bool and try to *var_dump* again, it's still o.k. ((bool)true, (bool)false).
But in IF condition it acts weird where every time it's seems to return true.
Any opinions on that? Recommendations?

Comment: Is `$someArray` supposed to be `$userPhotosArray`? It is not used in this code, and it is a little confusing.

Comment: Great! Now let's see... :)

Comment: @Emissary no, same again. var_dump shows (int)0, (int)1.

Comment: Seems fine to me: http://ideone.com/uWYwCl

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is this:

- print `<table>`

First iteration:

- print `<tr>`
- print `<td>`, `print_r` and `</td>`
- print `</tr>`

Second iteration

- print `<td>`, `print_r` and `</td>`

Finally

- print `</table>`

So your HTML looks like

```
<table>
   <tr><td> -- print_r -- </td></tr>
   <td> -- print_r -- </td>
</table>
```

and your browser is making the best of it.

Next code should work

```
print("<table>");
print("<tr>");

foreach ($userPhotosArray as $index => $photoInfo) {
   $ind = $index % 3;

   if ($index > 0 && $ind == 0)
      print("</tr><tr>");

   print("<td>");
   print_r($photoInfo);
   print("</td>");
}

print("</tr>");
print("</table>");
```

Comment: solved this issue by myself, but thanks for the notice about browser's 'unaided-close-tag' feature.
This code works fine - http://ideone.com/4JLF1R